# C# IMAP client - multiple connections to mail server

Tags: c#, tcp, imap

After experimenting with many IMAP API's, I have decided to write my own (Most are memory hogs, some just do not work, out of memory exception etc etc etc).

Anyway I have wrote some code that works (using TCPClient object) and its good so far. However, I want my one to be able to handle multiple requests to the mail server. For example:
Say I get a list of all the UIDs, then I cycle through this list getting what I want (Body, Header, etc) for each message.

The question is, how would I handle, multiple requests at the same time? So instead of looping through the UIDs one at a time I can instead process 10 at a time.

What would be the best approach here? An array of TCP Clients, each with its own thread?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general it's recommended that IMAP clients only have at most one connection to the server at all times. Not only does additional connections require valuable resources on the server but more important the IMAP specification does not guarantee that two connections can select the same mailbox at the same time. Relying on this capability being present on the server may render your client incompatible with those servers.

Instead you should use the protocol as efficient as possible. Note that many commands can operate on a set or range of UIDs. This allows you to make one singe request where you specify every UID instead of making one request for each UID separately.

Another good practice is to not request more data than what is currently needed. For example say that you have a list of messages. Then don't request detailed information for all of them, only request information for the messages that are currently visible.

I highly recommend that you read RFC 2683, [IMAP4 Implementation Recommendations](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2683.txt). It covers this among other things.

If you decide to use multiple connections anyway then a good approach is usually to use asynchronous operations and not use individual threads explicitly. Combination with some kind of run loop integration is often useful as well, that way your code is called when there is data to read instead of you code having to poll or explicitly check for it. This is often a good approach even if you're only using a single connection. Keep in mind that according to the IMAP protocol the server may send you responses even when you have not explicitly asked for them.

Comment: Wow thank you for such an awesome response. One technique that I am using to speed up processing of the mails is using they yield keyword, so I can process that mails as soon as I get them, and from there I can thread operations. Also, I have noticed that the server will send me commands even if I do not ask for them! Eg if a new mail is added while I am processing it sends me an update.

Comment: One more thing, I am using a StreamReader to read responses from the network stream. Since the mail server can send me responses without me asking for them, is the best approach to read the responses line-by-line and make sure it is what I want? (I ask this because in some cases I am using StreamReader.Read() to read a large chunk when I get the number of characters in the response. However this can become contaminated no? Hope that makes sense...)

Comment: That's tricky to get right. The problem is that the server will not indicate exactly where the responses which have to do with your command begins. The approach which I've been using have been to don't try to do that. If you keep track of the state you're in, which mailbox is selected and so on, then the responses you get will often make sense in only one way. So trying to figure out which lines has to do with the result from the command is often unnecessary.

Comment: However, the server will often mark where the result ends by sending a tagged status response. It's not enough since you still don't know where it started but if you keep track of the tag you used when you sent the command and always use unique tags for each command then you can have something like a callback which you can call to indicate whether the command was successful or not.